# Excel formula is not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What is wrong with this equation in Excel?

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(B$1,'Project Spread Sheet 4-14'!$H2)>0,'Sheet1 (2)'**!indirect("C"&((row(column())))),""),"")**
```

OR

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(B$1,'Project Spread Sheet 4-14'!$H2)>0,'Sheet1 (2)**'!$C((row(column())))),""),"")**
```

OR

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(B$1,'Project Spread Sheet 4-14'!$H2)>0,'Sheet1 (2)'**!$C((row(column(value))))),""),"")**
```

The part inside `**...**` is where the problem is. I need to reference a previous sheet in the C column, but with the row being a function of the current sheet position. What I mean is the current value of the current sheet column needs to be the input to the previous sheet row so that it returns C row(column number of current sheet).

They are meant to do the same thing.

Comment: It might help if you exposing what your data looks like and what you are trying to get the formula to do.

Comment: ok I've revised

Comment: How does (row(column(value))) evaluate to a value? Should it be something like (row(column($B$2))) ? Or (row(column(Sales))) if sales is a defined name?

Comment: I'm trying to pull the column number from the current column that the formula is in and then use that number as the row number to make it Sheet2!$C row number(of the column number)

Comment: Row()needs a full reference not just column like A2 D5 Column() is enough

Comment: Why are there two asterisks after the sheet name, i.e. 'Sheet1 (2)'**?

Comment: change the Value if False with: INDIRECT("'Sheet1 (2)'!$C"&column())

Comment: sorry the ** are supposed to have made it bold... disregard the asterisks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(B$1,'Project Spread Sheet 4-14'!$H2)>0,'Sheet1 (2)'!$C((row(column(value))))),""),"")
```

With:

`=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(B$1,'Project Spread Sheet 4-14'!$H2)>0,INDIRECT("'Sheet1 (2)'!$C"&column()),""),"")`

When you use Row(A2) it will return 2 but if you use Row(2) it will give error in formula Row needs reference not just value
It is better to use only Column() which will return the column number of the formula
Indirect will create the reference with $C and the column number

Comment: Thanks! My next question is how can you make this formula go faster if used on a large number of cells at once ... say 400*70,000? Thanks!